# Handlebars - Is this syntax valid?

Tags: handlebars.js

Is the following syntax valid in Handlebars.js?

```
{{#if !results}}
      <h1>There are no results</h1>
{{/if}}
```

The h1 should be displayed only if there are no results.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `unless` helper:

```
{{#unless results}}
  <h1>There are no results</h1>
{{/unless}}
```